# Running count shows all values instead of the total number of values

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

My data is stored in an Amazon Redshift db. I am attempting to get a running count of loans by month. This is my query:

```
SELECT 
TO_CHAR(LD.INITIAL_PURCHASE_DATE,'YYYY-MM') AS INITIAL_PURCHASE,
COUNT( LD.LOAN_ID) OVER (ORDER  BY TO_CHAR(LD.INITIAL_PURCHASE_DATE,'YYYY-MM') ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS TOTAL_LOANS
FROM LOANS_DETAILS
INNER JOIN LOANS L ON LD.LOAN_ID = L.ID
WHERE L.UNDERWRITING_STATUS IN ('...')
 AND LD.INITIAL_PURCHASE_DATE IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY
 LD.LOAN_ID, 
 LD.INITIAL_PURCHASE_DATE;
```

My expected result is as follow:

```
INITIAL_PURCHASE|TOTAL_LOANS
...|...
2016-10|369
2016-11|424
```

But instead I get one record for every day of the month like so

```
INITIAL_PURCHASE|TOTAL_LOANS
...|...
2016-10|366
2016-10|367
2016-10|368
2016-10|369
2016-11|371
```

I checked the source system and confirmed there were a total of 369 loans in October, 424 in November so I know data's correct.

How do I get the total number of loans per month?

---

**SOLUTION:
This is the correct query.**

```
SELECT 
TO_CHAR(LD.INITIAL_PURCHASE_DATE,'YYYY-MM') AS INITIAL_PURCHASE_DATE,
SUM(COUNT( LD_LOANS.LOAN_ID )) OVER (ORDER BY TO_CHAR(LD.INITIAL_PURCHASE_DATE,'YYYY-MM') ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS TOTAL_LOANS 
FROM LOANS_DETAIL LD
INNER JOIN LOANS L ON LD.LOAN_ID = L.ID
WHERE L.UNDERWRITING_STATUS IN ('...') AND LD.INITIAL_PURCHASE_DATE IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(LD.INITIAL_PURCHASE_DATE,'YYYY-MM')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `group by` needs to be by month, not day, and you need to remove `LOAN_ID` from the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(LD.INITIAL_PURCHASE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM') AS INITIAL_PURCHASE,
       SUM(COUNT( LD.LOAN_ID)) OVER (ORDER  BY TO_CHAR(LD.INITIAL_PURCHASE_DATE,'YYYY-MM') ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS TOTAL_LOANS
FROM LOANS_DETAILS LD INNER JOIN
     LOANS L
     ON LD.LOAN_ID = L.ID
WHERE L.UNDERWRITING_STATUS IN ('...') AND
      LD.INITIAL_PURCHASE_DATE IS NOT 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(LD.INITIAL_PURCHASE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM')
```

Notes:

- I think Amazon Redshift allows aliases in the `GROUP BY`, so you could use `GROUP BY INITIAL_PURPOSE, LD.LOAN_ID`.
- The `SUM(COUNT(*))` should give you the running sum.
- `LOAN_ID` should not be in the `GROUP BY` if you want totals by month.

Comment: I tried that already. `SUM(COUNT( LUT_LOANS.LOAN_ID) OVER (order  BY TO_CHAR(LUT_LOANS.INITIAL_PURCHASE_DATE,'YYYY-MM') ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING )) AS TOTAL_LOANS`  returns `[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: aggregate function calls may not have nested aggregate or window function;`

Comment: @Alan . . . If you look carefully, you'll see that this answer uses a window function bounding an aggregation function, not the other way around.

Comment: Sorry. Just realized my mistake. `sum(COUNT( * ))` worked. Thank you.

Comment: @Alan . . . As the OP, you can accept whichever answer you like.  I'm curious why you didn't accept this one, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you were aiming for.
You group by INITIAL_PURCHASE ('YYYY-MM') and do a running total on count(*).

```
SELECT      TO_CHAR(LD.INITIAL_PURCHASE_DATE,'YYYY-MM') AS INITIAL_PURCHASE

           ,sum(count(*)) OVER 
                 (ORDER BY TO_CHAR(LD.INITIAL_PURCHASE_DATE,'YYYY-MM')
                       ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS TOTAL_LOANS

FROM                    LOANS_DETAILS   LD
            INNER JOIN  LOANS           L 
            ON          LD.LOAN_ID = L.ID

WHERE       L.UNDERWRITING_STATUS IN ('...')
        AND LD.INITIAL_PURCHASE_DATE IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY    INITIAL_PURCHASE
```

---

P.s.
I think the alias `INITIAL_PURCHASE` should be recognized in the GROUP BY clause, if I am mistaken then use `TO_CHAR(LD.INITIAL_PURCHASE_DATE,'YYYY-MM')`

Comment: Sorry for the mess. This should be it.

Comment: Great :-) sorry again for the false suggestions

Comment: P.s. Please remember to mark the answer as correct. Thanks

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points so I couldn't upvote your answer. I marked it as accepted.